# How to get QIODevice-like signals for console input (stdin)?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm writing console app, based `QCoreApplication`, and I want to get signals, when user input something into stdin (whole line at once or by characters, it is not important for my app).

`QFile` not emit signals according to documentation, so any ideas how to get signal if user put in something to `stdin`?

At now I'm working with qt 4.8.7/linux/amd64, but I want port this code to macosx and windows in the future.

**Update**

I found solution that should work on *nix based `OS`, like `linux` and `mac os x`:

https://gist.github.com/gjorquera/2576569

But what about windows, would it also with with `QSocketNotfier`?

Comment: What else is your program doing while it's waiting for user input?  Anything?

Comment: @JohnZwinck It communicate via sockets with different services, so I want `async` solution based on signals/slots, because of it more simple to support then multithread code

Comment: According to this: http://www.qtcentre.org/archive/index.php/t-20357.html you can't use `QSocketNotifier` with `fileno(stdin)` on Windows.  But take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23164552/4323

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Unix (Linux, OS X), [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20642135/1329652) has a solution.

For Windows, you cannot use `QSocketNotifier`: instead, use a `QWinEventNotifier` on the console handle you obtain from `GetStdHandle` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23164552/4323)). The code will be almost identical to the Unix variant from the answer above.